# PHP echo and form values

Tags: php, jquery

I've completed a form (albeit not very well) and am currently trying to work out a 'confirmation' page in php that displays what the user will print after it's filled out and submitted. I've declared all the variables in php for every input field on the form - however, I have a section of the form that dynamically replicates and increments it's class numbers in jQuery.
For reference:

```
$('#replicate').click(function(){
    var $cloned = $('.container').clone();
    $cloned.find('input').val('');
    $cloned.appendTo($('.emptyContainer'));
    var container = $(".emptyContainer div").length;
    var containerNumber = container + 1;
    var containerClass = 'container' + containerNumber;
    $(".emptyContainer .container1").attr("class", containerClass);
```

So what the above does is that when the user hits the replicate button the container with all the input fields, well, replicates - and the new container that appears has a class number of '.container2', '.container3', etc. for as many times as the user needs. The input ids and names within each new container also increment accordingly. I've gone about declaring all the php variables for the first container - so if the first input id is "firstname1" the php variable is $firstname1 on my confirmation page.

What I'm trying to figure out, is how do I go about echoing out each new input on the confirmation page when "#firstname2", "#firstname3", get generated? Would that be something like a for loop? Excuse my ignorance, never done much in php.

Comment: Use arrays, not different variables for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a foreach loop against either $_GET or $_POST depending on the method you used.

Assuming you `POST`ed the form you could do something like.

```
foreach($_POST as $fieldName=>$fieldValue){
      echo $fieldName." = ".$fieldValue."<br/>";
}
```

A preferred method for this though would be when constructing the names of your fields use a name like `myfield[1]` instead of `myfield1`.

PHP will turn the square bracket notation into an array.

Comment: I'm still not understanding it sorry. Because this is a 'print preview' type of page I've been echoing the elements into related divs for readability (and later styling). If I implement a foreach like that I end up with a long list of all input names and values - is it possible to simply echo child input values of everything inside the empty container?